# Unresolved assembly reference with sandcastle

Tags: c#-4.0, documentation, sandcastle

I am trying to generate documentation with sandcastle help file builder. While building the project in the sandcastle i am getting the following error.

```
MRefBuilder : error : Unresolved assembly reference: Microsoft.Owin (Microsoft.Owin, Version=2.1.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35) required by Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.Owin [C:\Users\inkosah\Documents\Help\Working\GenerateRefInfo.proj]
Last step completed in 00:01:19.4610
```

Can anybody help me to resolve this issue? I also tried adding it separately to project references in the sandcastle but no help.

Answer (score 42, accepted):

**Solution 1** : Add missing references to a dummy project.

1. Create 'dummyProject' (ie class library)
2. In Visual Studio - Package Manager Console

   Install-Package Microsoft.Owin -Version 2.1.0.0 -ProjectName dummyProject

   Install-Package Microsoft.Owin.Security.OAuth -version 2.1.0.0 -ProjectName dummyProject
3. In Sandcastle Help Fil Builder - Project Explore, add two references

   Microsoft.aspNet.identity.Owin (dll found in ..\packages\Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.Owin.2.2.0\lib\net45)

   Microsoft.Owin (dll found in ..\packages\Microsoft.Owin.2.1.0\lib\net45\Microsoft.Owin.dll)

It looks like  MRefBuilder found that Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.Owin relies on Microsoft.Owin (== v 2.1.0) and not Microsoft.Owin (>= 2.1.0).

The main project is still using Microsoft.Owin 3.0.1.0

**Solution 2** : Ignore unresolved references

In Documentation (or SHFB) Project Properties / Plug-Ins :

1. Add "Assembly Binding Redirection" in "Plugs-Ins in This Project"
2. configure it to "ignore if Unresolved" "Microsoft.Owin" and "Microsoft.Owin.Security.OAuth"

Comment: thank you for sharing this - had same issue just now with 4.5.1...i ended up ignoring the missing references in my case.

Comment: Solution 2 worked perfectly for me as well. System.Net.Http.Formatting v5.2.3 has a reference to Newtonsoft v6.0.0.0 and we're currently using v9.0.0.0. Thanks!