# Sandcastle Unresolved Assembly Reference

Tags: c#, documentation-generation, sandcastle, assembly-references, shfb

I am trying to use Sandcastle Help File Builder to take the XML from my methods and create documentation for my project. I have the XML and the DLL added as Documentation Sources and have configured the Wildcard Assembly References plugin to add my bin which when building adds many references, including:

```
Added reference Microsoft.Owin.Security (D:\Andrew\Source\Branches\Andrew\Solution\bin\Microsoft.Owin.Security.dll)
```

but I still get have the build fail with this error:

```
MRefBuilder : error : Unresolved assembly reference: Microsoft.Owin.Security (Microsoft.Owin.Security, Version=3.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35) required by Owin.Security.Providers.AzureAD [D:\andrew.branoff@paretobiz.com\Sandcastle\Help\Working\GenerateRefInfo.proj]
```

Why is Sandcastle not finding the refrerence, if I ignore this one using Assembly Binding Redirection, another Owin reference is missing, if I ignore that, it's missing `Newtonsoft.JSON`

EDIT -

I verified the version numbers don't match up, but when I try a redirect to the version I have I still get the error

```
Loaded assembly binding redirect: Microsoft.Owin.Security, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null, Version(s) 1.0.0.0-4.0.0.0 redirect to Version 3.0.1.0
```

While ignoring the errors does allow me to build the help files, it does create holes in the documentation, not linking to the MSDN articles for those files which were ignored. I am looking to fix the issues I have, not ignore them or hack my way around them.

Comment: Can you confirm that the dll version you import matches what visual studio is expects, `3.0.0.0`?

Comment: @user5226582 I looked into that, and the version number is off, however when I redirect OldVersion 3.0.0.0 to NewVersion 3.0.1 or 3.0.1.0 still had the error

Comment: (Made a typo, *expecting) Possibly two of your referenced assemblies require `Microsoft.Owin.Security` of different versions. If you have this library of version `3.0.0.0`, you could try to re-add it manually. Or you could remove "Specific version" flag in reference properties. If neither helps, there's a similar question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29204603/unresolved-assembly-reference-with-sandcastle

Comment: @user5226582 I am redirecting everything from 1.0.0.0 to 3.0.1.0, which is the version of Owin we have, that redirect should work here, regardless of version numbers.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Unresolved assembly reference with sandcastle](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29204603/unresolved-assembly-reference-with-sandcastle)

Comment: @user5226582 No I read that one, my issue though has the proper fix in place but it is not working, I am redirecting versions. While ignoring does work, it creates holes in the documentation.